# Exception when using enhanced for loops while normal for loop works fine

Tags: java

I'm learning `java` and i got told that you can write a normal `for loop` shorter, by using a `enhanced for loop`.

Now i have that normal `for loop`:

```
int[] array1 = {3, 6, 9, 12};

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(array1[i]);
}
```

And this one returns

> 3 6 9 12

as expected.

When i use it as a `enhanced for loop`, like this way:

```
for (int i : array1)
{
    System.out.println(array1[i]);          
}
```

It returns

> 12

and then i get an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 6 out of bounds for length 4    at Tutorial.main(Tutorial.java:15)

Comment: `i` in the second loop is not the same thing as `i` in the first loop.

Comment: Just print `i`, not `array[i]`. The enhanced for loop gives you the values, not the indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second snippet `i` is no longer the index but the actual value, therefore to print it you should simply write:

```
for (int i : array1) {
    System.out.println(i); // no array1[i]          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree to what luk2302 said. You don't need an index in the enhanced for loop and the `i` in your code holds the value of `array1` in each iteration. The enhanced for loop can be used with arrays and Collections. The variables can be refactored in the following way to get a better understanding.

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
for (int number: numbers) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).